# How to access Google Cloud Storage Bucket from AI Platform job

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

My Google AI Platform / ML Engine training job doesn't seem to have access to the training file I put into a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Google's AI Platform / ML Engine requires you store training data files in one of their Cloud Storage buckets. Accessing locally from CLI works fine. However, when I send a training job (after ensuring the data is in the appropriate location in my Cloud Storage bucket), I get an error seeming to be due to no access to the bucket `Link URL`.

The error is from trying to read what looks to me like the contents of a web page that Google served up saying "Hey, you don't have access to this." I see this `gaia.loginAutoRedirect.start(5000,` and a URL with this flag at the end: `noautologin=true`.

I know permissions between AI Platform and Cloud Storage are a thing, but both are under the same project. The walkthroughs I'm using at very least imply that no further action is required if under the same project.

I am assuming I need to use the `Link URL` provided in the bucket Overview tab. Tried the `Link for gsutil` but the python (from Google's [CloudML Samples repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples)) was upset about using `gs://`.

I think Google's examples are proving insufficient since their example data is from a public URL rather than a private Cloud Storage bucket.

Ultimately, the error message I get is a Python error. But like I said, this is preceded by a bunch of gross `INFO` logs of HTML/CSS/JS from Google saying I don't have permission to get the file I'm trying to get. These logs are actually just because I added a print statement to the `util.py` file as well - right before `read_csv()` on the train file. (So the Python parse error is due to trying to parse HTML as a CSV).

```
... 
INFO    g("gaia.loginAutoRedirect.stop",function(){var b=n;b.b=!0;b.a&&(clearInterval(b.a),b.a=null)});
INFO    gaia.loginAutoRedirect.start(5000,
INFO    'https:\x2F\x2Faccounts.google.com\x2FServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.cloud.google.com%2F<BUCKET_NAME>%2Fdata%2F%2Ftrain.csv\x26followup=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.cloud.google.com%2F<BUCKET_NAME>%2Fdata%2F%2Ftrain.csv\x26service=cds\x26passive=1209600\x26noautologin=true',
ERROR   Command '['python', '-m', u'trainer.task', u'--train-files', u'gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/data/train.csv', u'--eval-files', u'gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/data/test.csv', u'--batch-pct', u'0.2', u'--num-epochs', u'1000', u'--verbosity', u'DEBUG', '--job-dir', u'gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/predictor']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 137, in <module>
    train_and_evaluate(args)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 80, in train_and_evaluate
    train_x, train_y, eval_x, eval_y = util.load_data()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/util.py", line 168, in load_data
    train_df = pd.read_csv(training_file_path, header=0, names=_CSV_COLUMNS, na_values='?')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 945, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 205, saw 961
```

To get the data, I'm more or less trying to mimic this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/tf-keras/trainer/util.py

Various ways I have tried to address my bucket in my copy of util.py:
`https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/<BUCKET_NAME>/data` (think this was the "Link URL" back in May)
`https://storage.cloud.google.com/<BUCKET_NAME>/data` (this is the "Link URL" now - in July)
`gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/data` (this is the URI - which gives a different error about not liking `gs` as a url type)

Comment: What sample are you trying to run and what is the error message you get?
How are you trying to access the data on GCS?

Comment: @nnegrey What do you mean by sample? I'm no longer following one of Google's toy problems and am trying to implement this on a real world problem with data not publicly available at some URL like the toy problems seem to be. _Additional error info added to the question._

Comment: Can you check inside the notebook who's performing the operations with
!gcloud auth list
and change it with
!gcloud config set account SA_NAME@YOUR_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
and further check its permissions on the bucket?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the "Link URL", rather the `gs://<bucket_name>` path, if you're following the samples. How are you trying to access the file?

Comment: @MonicaPC, I gave the Owner account 2 additional roles in the IAM settings - Storage Admin and ML Engine Admin. And confirmed the Owner account is active in the terminal I'm running this from. Still getting the same HTML/JS redirect output as above.  
 
@rpasricha, the exact error I alluded to above for when I use the `gs://` address:  `IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: 'gs'`. I get this when changing `util.py`'s `DATA_URL` to `gs://<bucket_name>`. The samples actually don't use `gs://` addresses for `DATA_URL` as far as I've seen.

Comment: Looks like the URL approach requires [cookie based authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/cookie-based-authentication) if it's not a public object.

Instead of using a URL, I would suggest using tf.gfile with a gs:// path, as is used in the [Keras sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/keras). If you need to download the file from GCS in a separate step, you can use the [GCS client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python).

Comment: @rpasricha, ah that `tf.gfile` does appear to be doing the trick! I thought I had already tried that, but perhaps something else was broken at that point - or I am mistaken. I'd select that as the answer if you wanted to post an answer.

Comment: @bhoeksem moved the comment to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transferring the answer from a comment above:

Looks like the URL approach requires [cookie based authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/cookie-based-authentication) if it's not a public object. Instead of using a URL, I would suggest using tf.gfile with a gs:// path, as is used in the [Keras sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/keras). If you need to download the file from GCS in a separate step, you can use the [GCS client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python).